# Pure Javascript's .closest() returns null

Tags: javascript, compatibility, closest

The built in function .closest() from vanilla javascript, supported on Firefox and Chrome is returning null. I am also not using jQuery for this project and it is not an option.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".image").closest(".container")
  // I know that this will only use the first element.
console.log(parent) // null
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="./images/bike.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="./images/sea.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I am using the latest version of Firefox Developer Edition.

Here's the MDN page that talks about the feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Also if there is a polyfill I can use instead of that, it would also be appreciated.

Comment: I added a code snippet into your question, but when I run it I see the desired result, not null. Have you got Chrome 41+ installed?

Comment: Test here, return the .container, `chrome 44.0.2403.125 m (64-bit)`.

Comment: I've checked it out on FIrefox v39 and Chrome v44. Worth mentioning that I'm using OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Compatibility list is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Works for me too - Firefox v39, standard edition, on Ubuntu.

Comment: jQuery is not an option for the project, but experimental, not fully cross browser functions are?

Comment: Well, the purpose of the project is to build a pure vanilla javascript to learn about the language.

Comment: Dig into the internals of jQuery then - it's only vanilla javascript anyway.  You'll find your polyfill therein.

Comment: Just walk up the `.parentNode` and check `.className` until you find what you want. Debug consoles these days are a bit too helpful showing you a html-like *thing* in the result window. In the old days we used to get an object instead and we used to explore the DOM by checking out the object attributes.

Comment: Hint: if you want to explore the properties of the DOMnode returned by `.querySelector` in the console, assign it to a variable. Then type the variable and type `.` - the autocomplete feature will show you a list of attributes/methods for the DOMnode

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` searches UP from your selected DOM element.

Since your container is the first element, it doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
.closest()
```

Only search the parents' nodes till to the DOM root. If the node is not one of the parent nodes, it will not work.